# Javascript - Script doesn't work after axios request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, request, axios

In my project, I use `axios` to facilitate Ajax requests. I created a script in which I add a listener to all my links, and then thanks to Axios, I make an Ajax request. And I want to perform a treatment after the Ajax request. I did some tests, and the code is good. But as soon as I put it in the then () function with `axios`, the code doesn't work anymore

This is my **PHP** code

```
<tr class="table-light">
  <td>
    <a href="{{path('notification_read', {'id': notif.id})}}" class="btn btn-link js-read" title="Marquer comme lu">
      <i class="fas fa-dot-circle" style="color: Dodgerblue;"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And **JS** :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function onClickBtnRead(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = this.href;
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
    $(tr).removeClass('table-light');

    this.href = '#';
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    $(this).removeAttr('title');

    var i = $(this).children();
    $(i).css('color', '#D3D3D3');

    axios.get(url).then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  document.querySelectorAll('a.js-read').forEach(function(link){
    link.addEventListener('click', onClickBtnRead);
  });
</script>
```

Like this, it works, but I want to put my code into the then() function, like this :

```
function onClickBtnRead(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const url = this.href;

  axios.get(url).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
    $(tr).removeClass('table-light');

    this.href = '#';
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    $(this).removeAttr('title');

    var i = $(this).children();
    $(i).css('color', '#D3D3D3');
  });
}
```

Ajax request works, but processing after is no longer taken into account

(Sorry for my english, I use a translator because I'm French )

Comment: log the value of this inside then, looks like "this" is the issue, context issue....

Comment: Okay it's work now, thanks !

Comment: What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a hook instead of a function?... I don't know what can be exactly the problem. The day I had to implement Axios, I used this code right here:

```
// execute simultaneous requests 
axios.all([
  axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/mapbox'),
  axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/phantomjs')
])
.then(responseArr => {
  //this will be executed only when all requests are complete
  console.log('Date created: ', responseArr[0].data.created_at);
  console.log('Date created: ', responseArr[1].data.created_at);
});
```

Maybe in the `then` function you can put the treatment you want to make to the data requested.

If you want to see more information, the source that I found useful was this: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-http-requests-like-a-pro-with-axios/